# SD card gets different name at every format

Tags: external-sd

Every time I format the SD card, or install new ROM., or move it to another phone, it comes with a different label

Something like
410E-1D17 or FEA7-1EF1 or BD05-14A1

How do I stop this mess and make it consistent ? 
Its screws up all apps that rely on the absolute path

Does it happen only on Xperia phones ?

Android M

Answer (score 1):

No you can't stop it from changing.

First you should know it's **not** the "name" for an SD card (technically "volume"). Even worse, "name" is an ambiguous term here. You should either use "product name" (for hardware) or "volume name/label".

This is, in fact, "[Volume Serial Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_serial_number)". It's a 32-bit integer so you see it represented with 8 hexadecimal numbers. It is subject to change whenever you format it.

As beeshyams noted, you may be able change it with command line utilities from **rooted** Android (you can always do so in a GNU/Linux system). To obtain the correct utilities, you should download Termux, and install a package named `mtools` in it:

```
apt install mtools tsu
```

Then follow [this guide](http://mclements.net/blogWP/index.php/2016/11/29/vfat-uuid-sd-cards-android-mount/) and run

```
tsu
mlabel -i /dev/block/xxx -N XXXXXXXX ::label
```

I haven't tested it but I'm afraid it isn't an easy job to do on Android. Better grab a Linux computer :)

Comment: Improving iBug's answer: Windows applications "AOMEI Partition Assistant" can edit "Volume Serial Number".